# Interactive Command Line Interface for Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking to create a cross-platform readline/linenoise type command line interface for an application in Qt.  I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if possible.  The terminal in which the user is operating should be able to receive commands via a command prompt.  This will be done in Qt, thus my question is: is there a Qt-esque way of doing this via signals and slots such that when a user enters a line into the terminal a slot can be called?

I understand that this can be fairly simply done using a QThread and running a blocking process to signal on a line being read.  This question is specifically geared towards using built-in Qt functionality.

Comment: Try reading up on [QTextStream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html).

Answer (score 0):

While attempting to discern a viable answer to this, I realized that my question was improperly phrased.  I was looking for what could be termed a `Terminal Emulator`.  There are several existing solutions to this, including QTermWidget.  However, it appears that there does not yet exist a non-UI based terminal emulator for Qt.  That is, in order to use these one must have an active UI instance of Qt, not merely employing a Qt Command Line application.

Going the route of using a simple Qt Command Line, it is not as simple as connecting something like a QTextStream and observing the output of the command line.  As with most command line programs, native, low-level processing must occur in order to assess things like the arrow keys.  Unfortunately QKeyPressEvent and the like require the UI to be running.

Comment: Since Qt is oriented around GUI development, I'm not sure it's the right tool for the job of developing a command-line application.  (Which isn't to say you couldn't make it work, only that there are probably other APIs out there that are more suited to the task)

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner I'm personally not a huge fan of using Qt for this purpose, but the goal is to create a cross-platform server solution with a minimal tech stack.  Qt is ubiquitously used and can operate in command line mode.  Also, alternative languages are not an option based on the developer team's experience.  This leaves C++/Qt as the best option for a "run anywhere" CLI, unless you have other C++ based solutions in mind.

Comment: Well, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)Ncurses is what came to my mind, not that I've used it myself.

Comment: ncurses works for Linux, but AFAIK, it's not ported to windows. Additionally, there's software like [linenoise](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise), but this is a non-Qt-Native solution.  I was curious if there was something available expressly from Qt, or something developed specifically for this.  As mentioned, it appears there's not... only UI based solutions.